# API Query (curl vs axios)

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a URL, that when using the following curl, I recieve the response as an array of objects,

```
curl --location --request GET "https://test.com"
```

But using axios, I get an empty array. The response.request.responseURL is same as the original url. So I am not sure if there any redirects

```
const options = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
};

const res = await axios("https://test.com", options);
console.log(res.data);
```

Any thoughts how to get the response using Axios?

Comment: Please give a reproducible example on how you perform the Axios call. Most likely you don't use the actual response of the request or something goes wrong during parsing/using the response

Comment: Also, you don't specify the `GET` method explicitly, is it provided implicitly by axios?

Comment: @Keimeno Yes, by default it is a GET request

Comment: @shwz, Are you sure that you are getting empty array? or are you seeing CORS issue in console?

Comment: try removing both headers from your axios request